# matlab, user inputs a matrix into variable

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this code for matlab to multiply matrixes how di i make the user add the matrixes and then use the matrixes in the code?

eg [n,m] = input(user inputs matrix here)

```
  [n,m] = size(A);
[p,q] = size(B);
C = zeros(n,p);

if p~=m
    error('Inner Matrix Dimensions Must Agree.')
end

for k = 1:n
    for j = 1:q
        temp=0;
        for i = 1:p
            temp = temp+(A(k,i)*B(i,j));
        end
        C(k,j) = temp;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in the script:

```
A = input('input array A ');
B = input('input array B ');

[n,m] = size(A);
[p,q] = size(B);
C = zeros(n,p);

if p~=m
    error('Inner Matrix Dimensions Must Agree.')
end

for k = 1:n
    for j = 1:q
        temp=0;
        for i = 1:p
            temp = temp+(A(k,i)*B(i,j));
        end
        C(k,j) = temp;
    end
end
```

or you can write the above as a function:

```
function C = matrixmultiply(A,B)

[n,m] = size(A);
[p,q] = size(B);
C = zeros(n,p);

if p~=m
    error('Inner Matrix Dimensions Must Agree.')
end

for k = 1:n
    for j = 1:q
        temp=0;
        for i = 1:p
            temp = temp+(A(k,i)*B(i,j));
        end
        C(k,j) = temp;
    end
end

end
```